# How to deal with metadata lines in pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file that has a header of metadata followed by the actual data in csv style. The data contains floats with commas. Like this:

```
title = someTitle
date = 20.0.2019
col= str1 str2 str3
2,49 42,01 -0,50
5,74 11,03 -0,43
....
```

I need the whole information in pandas (0.24.0) and want the data as floats.

```
df = pd.read_csv(path,sep='\t',decimal=',',names=[i for i in range(3)])
```

In this case, the decimal option makes no difference. I always get strings. Without the metadata, it works perfect. e.g. by:

```
pd.read_csv(...,skiprows=3)
```

To me, it seems like pandas assume the type of the rows by the first lines.

So how can tell pandas to ignore the metadata?

Comment: pandas does indeed have a skiprow equivalent. ```header=3``` More on the arguments here [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Your issue actually is the 'attribute =' prefixes. I think you need to get rid of those by cleaning first before loading with read_csv. Otherwise, load from Row 4 onwards and apply the column header separately

Comment: `pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=3)`

Comment: Are you sure `pd.read_csv(...,skiprows=3)` works? It did not work for me.

Comment: Yes, `pandas` tries to tokenize the data based on the first line to my knowledge. Either set `skip_rows` manually, or write some flexible code that reads the first few lines with the `.csv` module until it encounters a specific pattern that marks the last line of the header (in this case it seems it would be `col=`) and determine how many rows this is, then use `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_csv` can read from a file like object, so you should open the file, read 3 rows as headers, extract the column names and optionaly use them in `read_csv`. In addition, you can force the datatype with the `dtype` option. Code could be:

```
with open(path) as fd:
    headers = [ next(fd) for i in range(3) ]
    df = pd.read_csv(fd, sep=' ', decimal=',', dtype=np.float, names=...)
```

You can use the header part to set the column names if you want:

```
with open(path) as fd:
    headers = [ next(fd) for i in range(3) ]
    cols = headers[2].split('=', 1)[1].strip().split(' ')
    df = pd.read_csv(fd, sep=' ', decimal=',', dtype=np.float, names=cols)
```

You would get:

```
   str1   str2  str3
0  2.49  42.01 -0.50
1  5.74  11.03 -0.43
```