# Using Pandas to read data and skip metadata

Tags: python, pandas, metadata

**Background**

I have data files which consist of two parts: data in CSV format, and Metadata. I can use the method given here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722949/how-to-skip-header-and-footer-data-in-pandas-dataframe) and here [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481859/how-to-deal-with-metadata-lines-in-pandas-read-csv) to manually skip the Metadata portion by specifying the location/line number of the beginning of the Metadata.

Following is the sample of the data file:

[image: 3]

Here, you can see that I can specify the line number (420) manually and use the following code to skip the Metadata:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    metadata_location = [i for i, x in enumerate(f.readlines()) if 'Metadata' in x]
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    flat_data = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False, skiprows=lambda x: x >= metadata_location[0])

with open('data.csv') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False)
df = df[:420]
```

**Question**

How can I scan the file to capture the Metadata and then skip reading it? (I will need to process multiple such files, hence, I wish to write such a code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can pass the callable function to `skiprows` argument that will be evaluated against the row indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False otherwise. Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=False, skiprows=lambda x: x >= 420)
```

---

*UPDATE: To find the metadata location:*

```
import re

md_loc = 0
with open("data.csv") as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if re.search(r'^"Metadata:\s*"$', line):
            md_loc = idx
```

Comment: I have found a solution, not so elegant but a simple readlines() can be used to find out the location of the metadata and then skip reading it using your suggestion.
I have altered the code to reflect these changes. I am not aware of the protocol to tbe followed in such situations. How should I alter the question? It would be great if you could help in editing the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear.
If I got you right, you are looking for a way to scan all the lines and run the above code on each?

EDIT 1:

`for index, row in All_Patients_Chosen_Visit.iterrows():
             df = row[:420]`

See above code. Check if it works

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have altered the question to address it. Yes, I want the same, if possible using tools available with Pandas (I have fair idea about how to achieve it by reading the file as a text, and identify the location of the metadata).

Comment: See Edit1 above